# how to compare the elements of a vector to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

say i have a vector that contains 
" '.--', '.....', '-.', '-.-' "

and I have an array `std::string morse[39] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--.", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....","-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", ".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--.."};`

how would i compare the elements from the vector to the array to see if the elements from the vector are equal to any of the elements from the array and at what location they are in the array?

Comment: Advice -- Use a `std::unordered_set<std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` (i.e. hash table).  Using an array to store the morse code is not the optimal data structure to use here.

Comment: iterate over the vector; use std::find to search the element from the vector in the array. std::find should deliver an pointer the element found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::find` on the array.  An iterator is returned, then if the string was found, use `std::distance` to determine where the item was found.

Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int get_morse_position(const std::string& code)
{
    static const std::array<std::string, 39> morse = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--.", "-.", "---", ".--.", 
                                 "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....",
                                 "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", ".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--.."};    

    // search for the item
    auto iter = std::find(std::begin(morse), std::end(morse), code);

    // if item is found, get the distance from the beginning of the array
    if ( iter != morse.end())
        return static_cast<int>(std::distance(morse.begin(), iter));

    // not found, so return -1
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test = {".--", ".....", "-.", "-.-"};
    for (auto& code : test)
       std::cout << get_morse_position(code) << "\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
22
30
13
10
```